# Editar usando método PUT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, crud

Queria realizar uma edição por método PUT, mas estou com algum problema com a query string. Não consegui resolver até o momento por ser programador novo em .NET Core. Já tentei definir route, usar FromBory, mas até o momento sem sucesso.
Essa é minha view:

```
@model Teste_Tria_Software.Models.Cliente

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditPut";
}

<h4>Cliente</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="put" asp-controller="Clientes" asp-action="EditPutCliente">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ClienteID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CPF" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CPF" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CPF" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NOME" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NOME" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NOME" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EMAIL" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EMAIL" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EMAIL" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DATA_CRIACAO" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DATA_CRIACAO" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DATA_CRIACAO" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Esse é meu controller:

```
        [HttpPut("Clientes/EditPutCliente/{id}")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditPutCliente(long id, [FromBody] Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (id != cliente.ClienteID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(cliente);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ClienteExists(cliente.ClienteID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(cliente);
        }
```

Esse é o erro:

Não foi possível encontrar a página deste localhostNenhuma página da web foi encontrada para o endereço da Web:https://localhost:44313/Clientes/EditPutCliente?ClienteID=1&CPF=99999999997&NOME=José+da+Silva+Rodrigues&EMAIL=Jose%40outlook.com.br&DATA_CRIACAO=2021-06-30T10%3A59%3A00.000&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8LJGPZwdgPxIipjNoNuamp5-7DShQE9W3B9KEw_O8rMVaLSTXIg-SuOfk1i0nQzWUMzlxUnPlOO7gfDSPBI3SzARA3wglqmPDPrrkzqbMkWRorEp4RrK88U39NZljwl2Gry_jTTpZMOoFNVJWLH6uqw
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: 2 coisas erradas. 1: o Id do cliente precisa fazer parte da rota, não da querystring. 2. Não é possível fazer uma requisição PUT com um form HTML, apenas GET ou POST.

Comment: Como posso usar o método PUT por ViewModel?